# ERROR:optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: python, pytorch

Here is code:

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from torch_geometric.datasets import Planetoid
from torch_geometric.nn import Node2Vec
from collections import namedtuple

dataset = Planetoid(root='tmp/', name='Cora')
data = dataset[0]

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
model = Node2Vec(data.edge_index, embedding_dim=128, walk_length=20,
                 context_size=10, walks_per_node=10, num_negative_samples=1,
                 sparse=True).to(device)
loader = model.loader(batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

optimizer = torch.optim.SparseAdam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

when running these codes

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SparseAdam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

I got:

```
ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list
```

I am so confused and I can't solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try printing what `model.parameters` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

[`to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to) modifies the model in place and returns a tensor.

This is probably why your model's parameters is an empty list.

Try modifying your code to:

```
model = Node2Vec(data.edge_index, embedding_dim=128, walk_length=20,
             context_size=10, walks_per_node=10, num_negative_samples=1,
             sparse=True)
model.to(device)
```